# Admob ads loading but not showing

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

So in my LIBGDX game I'm trying to impement Admob ads.

They load fine but just wont show, even after a 60 second refresh or pressing home button and entering the game again.

I followed some answers on this site, but none of them helped.

Here's the code of Android Launcher class:

```
   public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdHander{

        private static final String TAG = "AndroidLauncher";
        protected AdView adView;
        private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
        private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

        Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what){
                    case SHOW_ADS:
                        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case HIDE_ADS:
                        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };


        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            View gameView = initializeForView(new Main(this), config);

            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

// HERE I IMPLEMENTED ADMOB TEST ID FOR BANNERS
            adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
            adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    int visibility = adView.getVisibility();
                    adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);
                    adView.setVisibility(visibility);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Ad loaded");
                }
            });

            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            adView.loadAd(builder.build());

            layout.addView(gameView);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

            layout.addView(adView, adParams);


            setContentView(layout);

            config.useImmersiveMode = true;
            initialize(new Main(this), config);
        }

        @Override
        public void showAds(boolean show) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
        }
    }
```

What have I did wrong?

Comment: Is this issue is solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void showAds(boolean show) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest it should look similar to this one :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.serveroverload.recorder"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.serveroverload.recorder.ui.HomeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

             <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
            <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```